# XSLT insert 2 distinct elements in XML problem

Tags: xml, xslt

Following is my original XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncItemMaster>
  <ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
      <LogicalID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.051">lid://in.m4.m4</LogicalID>
      <ComponentID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.20210322170049">M4BEX</ComponentID>
      <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2021-06-17T18:42:31.420Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>e99a31bc-4ad5-45e1-a27b-10b27b9511c6</BODID>
  </ApplicationArea>
  <DataArea>
    <ItemMaster>
      <ItemMasterHeader>
        <Description>JADE COLL 5-5/8 X 48 W/PAD</Description>
        <Description type="ShortName">4MM GEMCORE ARCTIC 12MIL</Description>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="1">00006002</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code sequence="1" listID="Item Types">E01</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="Free1">679QB</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="Free2">0.00</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
      </ItemMasterHeader>
    </ItemMaster>
  </DataArea>
</SyncItemMaster>
```

I need to insert 2 elements.

1. insert another Classification inside ItemMasterHeader

```
      <Classification>
        <Codes>
          <Code listID="RESPQQQ" sequence="1"></Code>
        </Codes>
      </Classification>
```

2. Insert another Property inside UserArea

```
      <Property>
    <NameValue name="RESPZ">zzzz</NameValue>
  </Property>
```

and the resulting XML is expecting like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncItemMaster>
  <ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
      <LogicalID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.051">lid://in.m4.m4</LogicalID>
      <ComponentID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.20210322170049">M4BEX</ComponentID>
      <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2021-06-17T18:42:31.420Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>e99a31bc-4ad5-45e1-a27b-10b27b9511c6</BODID>
  </ApplicationArea>
  <DataArea>
    <ItemMaster>
      <ItemMasterHeader>
        <Description>JADE COLL 5-5/8 X 48 W/PAD</Description>
        <Description type="ShortName">4MM GEMCORE ARCTIC 12MIL</Description>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="1">00006002</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code sequence="1" listID="Item Types">E01</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
           <Code listID="RESPQQQ" sequence="1"></Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="Free1">679QB</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="Free2">0.00</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="RESPZ">zzzz</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
      </ItemMasterHeader>
    </ItemMaster>
  </DataArea>
</SyncItemMaster>
```

And my XSLT is ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" byte-order-mark="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <!-- Copy whole source doc. to target -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Add RESP element inside ItemMasterHeader -->
  <xsl:template match="//*:ItemMasterHeader">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
      <Classification>
        <Codes>
          <Code listID="RESPQQQ" sequence="1"></Code>
        </Codes>
      </Classification>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <!-- Add RESP element inside UserArea -->

  <xsl:template match="//*:ItemMasterHeader/*:UserArea">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/> <!-- now does attrs too -->
      <Property>
        <NameValue name="RESPZ">zzzz</NameValue>
      </Property>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the translated XML is like this...

```
<SyncItemMaster>
  <ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
      <LogicalID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.051">lid://in.m4.m4</LogicalID>
      <ComponentID schemeVersionID="16.0.0.20210322170049">M4BEX</ComponentID>
      <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2021-06-17T18:42:31.420Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>e99a31bc-4ad5-45e1-a27b-10b27b9511c6</BODID>
  </ApplicationArea>
  <DataArea>
    <ItemMaster>
      <ItemMasterHeader>
        <Description>JADE COLL 5-5/8 X 48 W/PAD</Description>
        <Description type="ShortName">4MM GEMCORE ARCTIC 12MIL</Description>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="1">00006002</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code sequence="1" listID="Item Types">E01</Code>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
        <UserArea>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="Free1">679QB</NameValue>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <NameValue name="Free2">0.00</NameValue>
          </Property>
        </UserArea>
        <Classification>
          <Codes>
            <Code listID="RESPQQQ" sequence="1"/>
          </Codes>
        </Classification>
      </ItemMasterHeader>
    </ItemMaster>
  </DataArea>
</SyncItemMaster>
```

The Codes element is inside Classification.
Could anybody can tell me what's wrong with my XSLT?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: *"The Codes element is inside Classification."* The Codes element is inside Classification in both your expected and the actual output. If the real problem is that the added .Classification comes after UserArea, then you have your answer. If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to situate the new nodes after their same-name nodes, copy all children under `ItemMasterHeader` and `UserArea` templates, adding new sections in corresponding order:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" byte-order-mark="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <!-- Copy whole source doc. to target -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Add RESP element inside ItemMasterHeader -->
  <xsl:template match="ItemMasterHeader">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Description|Classification"/>
      <Classification>
        <Codes>
          <Code listID="RESPQQQ" sequence="1"></Code>
        </Codes>
      </Classification>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="UserArea"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Add RESP element inside UserArea -->
  <xsl:template match="UserArea">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Property"/>
      <Property>
        <NameValue name="RESPZ">zzzz</NameValue>
      </Property>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<!--   Identy template  -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<!--    New element added after last "classification" element -->
    <xsl:template match="//Classification[last()]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <Classification>
            <Codes>
                <Code listID="RESPQQQ" sequence="1"/>
            </Codes>
        </Classification>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--    New element added after last "Property" element -->
    <xsl:template match="//Property[last()]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <Property>
            <NameValue name="RESPZ">zzzz</NameValue>
        </Property>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```